# Using xsl:key to store result of boolean expression

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, xslkey

In my transformation there is an expression some elements are repeatedly tested against. To reduce redundancy I'd like to encapsulate this in an `xsl:key` like this (not working):

```
<xsl:key name="td-is-empty" match="td" use="not(./node()[normalize-space(.) or ./node()])" />
```

The expected behaviour is the key to yield a boolean value of `true` in case the expression is evaluated successfully and otherwise `false`. Then I'd like to use it as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="td[not(key('td-is-empty', .))]" />
```

Is this possible and in case yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with XSLT 1.0 a key value is always of type string so in your sample the key value with either be the string `true` or the string `false`. You could then call `key('td-is-empty', 'true')` to find all `td` element nodes for which the expression is true and `key('td-is-empty', 'false')` to find all `td` elements for which the expression is false.

You seem to want to do something differently with your key however, like storing the result of the `use` expression for each `td` node, based on node identity. I don't think that is how keys work in XSLT.

[edit]
You might however be able to express your requirement as

```
<xsl:template match="td[count(. | key('td-is-empty', 'false')) = count(key('td-is-empty', 'false'))]">...</xsl:template>
```

That matches those `td` elements which are a member of the set of elements found by `key('td-is-empty', 'false')`.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like I had some misunderstanding on how keys work. I will try your suggestion, but probably it won't simplify my code help unless the condition becomes more complex